# Find secondary dependencies in CMake config files

Tags: cmake, configuration, cmake-modules

Following modern CMake guidelines (e.g. see https://www.slideshare.net/DanielPfeifer1/effective-cmake, particularly slide 46), I am trying to write out a `PkgConfig.cmake` file for my `Pkg`.

`Pkg` depends on `Foo` which in turn depends on `Bar`. Neither `Foo` nor `Bar` have config files - rather I am using `FindFoo.cmake` and `FindBar.cmake` to find them.

My `PkgConfig.cmake` file looks like this

```
set(Pkg_LIBRARIES Pkg::Pkg)

include(CMakeFindDependencyMacro)

find_dependency(Foo)  # Use FindFoo.cmake find and import as target Foo::Foo
                      # Foo depends on Bar which is similarly imported using
                      # FindBar.cmake as target Bar::Bar

include("${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/PkgTargets.cmake")
```

My resultant `PkgTargets.cmake` looks like

```
add_library(Pkg::Pkg STATIC IMPORTED_
set_target_properties(Pkg::Pkg PROPERTIES
  INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES "Foo::Foo")

# Load information for each installed configuration
.
.
.
```

**My question is how can I avoid other packages importing `Pkg` into their project from having to specify where `Foo` and more importantly where `Bar` is to be found?**

Doesn't it defeat the purpose of building transitive dependencies if the locations of `Foo` and `Bar` packages have to be specified again either through variables `Foo_ROOT` and `Bar_ROOT` or `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`?

My Pkg already knows where it was found, so should I parse/set `Foo_ROOT` and `Bar_ROOT` and put it into my `PkgConfig.cmake` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is how can I avoid other packages importing `Pkg` into their project from having to specify where `Foo` and more importantly where `Bar` is to be found?

It is perfectly allowed for `PkgConfig.cmake` to specify (hint) locations of its dependencies.

> My Pkg already knows where it **was found**, so should I parse/set `Foo_ROOT` and `Bar_ROOT` and put it into my `PkgConfig.cmake` file?

Note, that `XXXConfig.cmake` files are generally prepared for the installed project to be *moved* into other directory on the *build machine* or, more important, to be **copied** into **other machine** and be used there.

Because **location** of `Foo` and `Bar` on the *other machine* **may differ** from one on the *build machine*, knowing their locations on build machine cannot help to find them on the target machine.

Nevertheless, it is up to you (as the project's developer) to specify project's usage constraints. You may, e.g., specify that the project can be used only on that machine where it has been built. In that case reusing build locations of `Foo` and `Bar` in the `PkgConfig.cmake` script is justified.

Moreover, even when allowing to copy the installed project into other machine, you still can use build locations of `Foo` and `Bar` as a **hint** for search them in the `PkgConfig.cmake`. So, if the project will be used on the *same machine* where it was built, then dependencies will be found without an user intervention. The same is true if the project will be copied to the *other machine* which has `Foo` and `Bar` on the same locations as on the *build machine*.

Comment: I don't ever have the use case of copying the Config file into another machine and using it. Even if I do, it may not work because the Targets file that it includes may have hardcoded include and link directory locations that are autogenerated by CMake. So, per your suggestion, putting hints as to where to find the packages should work just fine it seems

Comment: "the Targets file that it includes may have hardcoded include and link directory locations that are autogenerated by CMake." - If you correctly set include directories for exported targets, then CMake won't generate absolute paths for them in the config file.

Comment: I don't have hardcoded paths for my project's includes and libraries in the Config file; but the dependency library locations are hard paths and I don't know how to keep CMake from putting those in

Comment: "but the dependency library locations are hard paths" - Make sure that such dependencies are behind of IMPORTED targets (that is, properties of the IMPORTED targets are allowed to be paths which are out of the install prefix). CMake doesn't "export" IMPORTED targets into the auto-generated export files. Instead, it allows the config file to manually create these targets and fill their properties.